# Modern PHP based issue trackers that offers migration from Trac

Tags: php, issue-tracker

Our team has used [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/) for 15 years and we are ready to move off of the platform.

Are there any modern issue trackers based on PHP that will also offer some kind of tool to migrate all of our data from Trac? I was even entertaining [MantisBT](https://www.mantisbt.org), however the only [migrate tool](https://orus.io/christophe.devienne/trac2mantis/-/tree/branch/default) I found is almost 15 years old and is not working for us, and we're weary of that rabbit hole.

The system can be commercial, but open source would be adventitious. At a minimum, we need an ability to install on our own servers due to PHI. A migration tool to capture all of our trac tickets, milestones, components, and attachments is 100% needed.